# How to install and run a perl app using perlbrew in osx

Tags: macos, perl, installation

I want to run a perl application on osx. I installed it using:

```
cpanm Graph::Easy
```

I was expecting that it would run as easily as applications installed with `homebrew`. But I got some errors:

```
$ echo "[ Bonn ] - car -> [ Berlin ]" | /Users/mertnuhoglu/perl5/bin/graph-easy
Can't locate Graph/Easy.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Graph::Easy module) (@INC contains: /Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Perl/5.18 /Network/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Network/Library/Perl/5.18 /Library/Perl/Updates/5.18.2/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Perl/Updates/5.18.2 /System/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/5.18 /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18 .) at /Users/mertnuhoglu/perl5/bin/graph-easy line 7.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /Users/mertnuhoglu/perl5/bin/graph-easy line 7.
```

I don't know why this error occurred. Is there any installation method like homebrew in perl? I found `perlbrew` but I couldn't find out how to use it exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Perlbrew is a tool to install multiple flavors of perl on a single system, and activate one or another.

The error message you have means:

- that you already have a functional perl installation.
- that the module is not installed, which is normal, because it isn't a core perl module.

You should use the **cpan** or **cpanm** (if available) command to install the module.

Typically:

```
cpan install Graph::Easy
```